# Image stitching using JavaCV: compilation error

Tags: opencv, javacv, image-stitching

I have tried this code and it is gives error with the stitcher. whether I have use 
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_stitching.Stitcher;
it is give the same error with the stitcher. If you can please can I have a solution for this issue please.
Thank you.

code is..

```
public class ImageStitching {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MatVector images = new MatVector(2);
        images.put(0,cvLoadImage("sample1.png"));
        images.put(1,cvLoadImage("sample2.png"));

        IplImage result = new IplImage(null);
        int status = stitcher.stitch(images,result);

        if( status == stitcher.OK )
        {
            cvSaveImage("result.png", result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tell us what the error is...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 stitcher cannot be resolved
 stitcher cannot be resolved to a variable

 at ImageStitching.main(ImageStitching.java:24)                       java:24 is  int status = stitcher.stitch(images,result);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared `stitcher` in your code...

`Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher.createDefault(false);`

Comment: Thank you.The error was solved.But the result image does not appear any where in the project.I am new to javacv. If you can please can I have a solution for this error please,Thank you

Comment: First of all, if it solved the problem, you should validate the answer. Then, the result image is actually "result". You should try to print it in a canvas (have a look at the JavaCV example [here](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/OpenCV2_Cookbook_Examples)).

Comment: Sorry,It is alright to load the result to the canvas,but there is no such a image as result.that is  mean                         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at canvas.showImage(image);com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame.showImage(CanvasFrame.java:366)
 at com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame.showImage(CanvasFrame.java:363)
 at ImageStitching.main(ImageStitching.java:54)
This error is there java:54 is  canvas.showImage(image);

Comment: Because in your case you must use "result" and not "image": `canvas.showImage(result);`

Comment: i have run this code with these lines of codes              result = cvLoadImage("result.jpg");
final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("My Image", 1);
 canvas.showImage(result);  error was Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame.showImage(CanvasFrame.java:366)
 at com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame.showImage(CanvasFrame.java:363)
 at ImageStitching.main(ImageStitching.java:57) java:57 is canvas.showImage(result);

Comment: You should validate the answer. For your second question, you apparently save "result.png" and try to open "result.jpg".

Comment: Sorry it should be "result.png" and if it is "result.png" it is give the same error.I think the thing is there is no any result.png created from this code.

Comment: Then this is another question. Validate this one and put the new code in a new question.

Comment: Thank you i have edited the code here  if( status != stitcher.OK )
      {
       
          //cvSaveImage("result.png", result);
          System.out.println("cant stitch image"+status);
          return;
         
      } the error display as"cant stitch image1"

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question. You should validate this one (click on the green mark next to the score) and continue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624953/image-stitching-using-javacv-opencv-image-stitcher).