# Image stitching: NullPointerException

Tags: opencv, javacv, image-stitching

I have run this code. It seems to be that result.png is not generated as a result:

```
public class ImageStitching {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MatVector images = new MatVector(2);
        images.put(0,cvLoadImage("sample1.png"));
        images.put(1,cvLoadImage("sample2.png"));

        IplImage result = new IplImage(null);
        int status = stitcher.stitch(images,result);

        if( status == stitcher.OK )
        {
            cvSaveImage("result.png", result);
        }

       result = cvLoadImage("result.png");

       final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("My Image", 1);

       // Request closing of the application when the image window is closed.
       canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       // Show image on window.
       canvas.showImage(result);

      }
}
```

and the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame.showImage(CanvasFrame.java:366)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame.showImage(CanvasFrame.java:363)
    at ImageStitching.main(ImageStitching.java:50)

java:50 is canvas.showImage(result);
```

Comment: where are you creating your stitcher instance?

Comment: sorry i have missing it here Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher.createDefault(false); I had include it as the first line of the main method.sorry I have missed it here.If the instance was there it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `result` is null when you call `showImage`.

The problem in your code is that you test if the status is OK (`if ( status == stitcher.OK )`), and then you try to load the file anyway. Your code should be something like:

```
if ( status != stitcher.OK )
{
    std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Then you would probably see that the problem comes from the stitching.

---

Moreover, you don't need to write `result` to a file before showing it.

Comment: Are you even sure that "sample1.png" and "sample2.png" are opened successfully?

Comment: How do you know this? Did you apply `canvas.showImage` on them?

Comment: By the way, [you don't behave correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/about) with your questions. When there is a valid answer to your question, you must validate it. You cannot use a question as an online assistance for your compilation problems.

Comment: yes. just check them with this code result = cvLoadImage("sample1.png");
final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("My Image", 1);
canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
canvas.showImage(result);

Comment: Then you should investigate into the stitcher status, and this is another question. If it is not `status.OK`, then it is something else that will give you hints.